# What is silicalemma and what is plasmalemma in diatom algae and how do they differ?

Tags: botany, cell-membrane, algae

I try to understant the morphology (cytology?) of diatom algae. Does someone can describe what is silicalemma and what is plasmalemma in diatoms and how do they differ? Or they are the same?